# Hide but not remove Image button CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

In CKEditor, I added my custom image button, which directly trigger a file input. However, images can only be rendered when the Image plugin is in use.

I don't want to have 2 image buttons on the toolbar, is there a way to hide the Image button, but still use it (like display: none but in a more structural way?)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SAZ's answer is likely what you need, but if you really just want to hide but not remove the button as per question title, why not just do a display: none, as you yourself referred to?: `a.cke_button__image {display: none;}`

Comment: Thanks @NickRice, I did actually use {display: none} but was looking for a better way with javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since 'CKEditor 4.1' you have something which is called [Advanced content filtering](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).
This allows you set enable or disable certain tags.

The easiest way to allow the images to be displayed is to add

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

in your config.js file. But this will allow everything.

To just add the enablement of the 'img' tag you can add it in the 'extraAllowedContent' element when you create the CKEditor

```
    var myEditor = CKEDITOR.replace(editorId, {
    extraAllowedContent : 'img(*){*}[*]'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is removeButton option for CKEditor config, will it work for you ?

`config.removeButtons = 'Image';`

Comment: Thanks @SAZ, I don't want to remove the impact of Image, just want to hide the button. Kind of weird but my custom image requires Image to be included in the list, haven't find a better way to intervene Image's functionality